# Selenium finding xlink:href with python

Tags: python, selenium

How would I find this element on a page using Python?

xlink:href="/assets/images/add.4dcdff54.svg"

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so good with Python or XLink but if you wish to find an element which has an anchor tag use  : -

```
String path = "//a [@href='page_name.php']";
WebElement navbar = (new WebDriverWait(m_driver, 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(path)));
```

The code above is written in Java, it would be great if someone can edit this and write an equivalent code for Python.

Comment: In Python `path = "//a [@href='page_name.php']";
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, path))`

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll give it a try this morning.